# Is there a difference between using struct.calcsize() and len() in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, bit-manipulation

Is using `struct.calcsize()` always the same as simply using `len()` to get the number of bytes in a struct?

For example:

```
>>> import struct
>>> a = struct.pack('I', 107)
>>> len(a)
4
>>> struct.calcsize('I')
4
```

For my small set of tests, they seem to agree. Is there a reason to prefer one over the other? Is it safe to use them interchangeably?

Comment: You may have a format in a variable whose size you need to know before you can decide what string to try to unpack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct.calcsize` doesn't require you to actually pack data. This saves time and memory, and is more convenient if you don't actually have any data to pack.

If you have a format string and you want to know how big the results of packing data in that format *would* be, use `struct.calcsize`. If you have already-packed data and you want to know how big it is, use `len`.